# Change the default data installed when setting up WordPress

Tags: database

Is there documentation somewhere on how to change the default data that is entered into the WordPress database when setting up a new database?

I want to change the default category and add a couple others. Change the default post. Set a different theme, activate a couple plugins all by default. All of this to make it easy for setting up multiple sites that are all similar.

Comment: which default data do you mean - the "Hello world" post and its comment, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I added more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Initialization Script for “Standard” Aspects of a WordPress Website?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/initialization-script-for-standard-aspects-of-a-wordpress-website) and my plugin [WordPress Basic Settings](https://github.com/toscho/WordPress-Basic-Settings) for details. You may also use a custom `install.php` but that’s somewhat tricky for multi-site setups.