# Automatically delete default posts and pages on theme install?

Tags: posts, themes, pages, activation, customization

Is there a way to automatically delete the default wordpress posts and pages when activating theme theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following question gives you some insights how you can create an initialization script which should cleanup a fresh WordPress installation. It's not complete but it's a good startpoint.

-> [Initialization Script for “Standard” Aspects of a WordPress Website?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/initialization-script-for-standard-aspects-of-a-wordpress-website)

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  This also helped with some other things I was looking for.