# Creating Multiple Menus when using the TwentyTen Theme?

Tags: themes, menus, theme-twenty-ten, design

How to get multiple menus in TwentyTen theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **several steps to creating additional menus using the new menu system in WordPress** in the TwentyTen theme or any WordPress theme *(of which some of these steps can be done out of order)*. In addition, I'm going to highly recommend you create a child theme based on TwentyTen instead of modifying it directly:

1. **Create a Child Theme** based on the Twenty Ten theme.
2. **Register a Theme Location** in your theme's `functions.php` file.
3. **Create a New Menu** using the admin console of your website.
4. **Associate the New Menu and the Theme Location** using your admin console.
5. **Call `wp_nav_menu()` in the Template File** of your theme where you want the menu to appear.
6. **Style your Menu** so that it integrates visually with your site.

So let's be on with it!

### 1. Create a Child Theme

Creating **a child theme is extremely simple** and gives you the benefit of being able to upgrade TwentyTen if a new version comes out without haven't to worry about loosing your changes.

*Yes, there's a small chance your changes will be incompatible with the new version, and if you make copies of TwentyTen files and modify them for your child theme you'll need to reapply those changes, but that's much better than loosing your changes when the theme is upgraded.*

But rather than duplicate my answer from another question where I suggested child themes I'll just point you there:

- [**Customizing a WordPress theme without changing it? (Use Child Themes)**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290/customizing-a-wordpress-theme-without-changing-it/291#291)

For the examples in the rest of this answer I'm going to call the child theme *"Himanshu"*.

### 2. Register a Theme Location

Registering a theme location **is very straightforward using the `register_nav_menus()` function** *(yes, it would have been really nice if they had called that function `register_nav_menu_locations()`, but I digress...)*

I'll create a ***"Footer"*** menu for this example.

In my example notice how I reference `'primary'` in a comment; I do that so you'll see what the default nav menu location is named and that you don't have to define it yourself.  Also note that I used to `__()` translation function and specified the name of the child theme as the translation domain.

If you are using a child theme you need to create a `functions.php` file in your theme to house this function but if you are modifying a theme them just find `functions.php` and add it to the end:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
  //'primary' => __('Primary Menu Area','himanshu'), ==> Primary defined by default
  'footer'  => __('Footer Menu Area','himanshu'),
));
```

If you are writing code for your own theme and don't need to distribute it to others or worry about translations you can just do this:

```
register_nav_menus(array('footer'=>'Footer Menu Area'));
```

### 3. Create a New Menu

Next let's create your footer menu located by navigating to the **Menus** option of the **Appearance** menu in the admin console. Click the *"+"* to add a menu, type the name of your menu and then click *"Create Menu"*:

[image: Creating a Nav Menu in WordPress 3.x]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101010-042401.png))</sub>

**Note** that you'll often name your menu the same as the name of your menu location but that's not required and **WordPress treats menus and their menu locations them as separate entities**.

Be sure to **add some options to your menu** or it will be of little use. Select the options you need using the admin console, add them to your menu and then save *(in my screenshot I only show selecting "Pages" for menu options but you can mix and match what ever types of menu options WordPress provides)*:

[image: Added Options to a Nav Menu in WordPress 3.x]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101010-044801.png))</sub>

### 4. Associate the New Menu and the Theme Location

Associating your new menu with your desired theme location is easy, just use WordPress' admin console:

[image: Associating a Nav Menu with a Theme Menu Location in WordPress 3.0]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101010-045447.png))</sub>

### 5. Call `wp_nav_menu()` in the Template File

Now we need to head back to code. I made a copy of `footer.php` from the TwentyTen theme and copied it to the *"Himanshu"* theme directory. Here's what the first 18 lines look like:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the id=main div and all content
 * after.  Calls sidebar-footer.php for bottom widgets.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Himanshu (based on Twenty Ten)
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
?>
  </div><!-- #main -->

  <div id="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div id="colophon">
```

I inserted the call to `wp_nav_menu()` along with wrapper HTML right after `<div id="colophon">` on line 18 so lines 13 thru 24 now look like the following:

```
</div><!-- #main -->

<div id="footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div id="colophon">
    <div id="footernav" role="navigation">
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
          'container_class' => 'menu-footer',
          'theme_location' => 'footer'
        ));
      ?>
    </div>
```

**Note** I chose to call the wrapper `footernav` and the inner container `menu-footer` and I followed TwentyTen's lead and set `role="navigation"`. However, **the most important aspect of the code is `'theme_location' => 'footer'`** which matches up to our named theme location in step #2.

All these steps gives us a Footer menu that looks like the following:

[image: A Footer Nav Menu in WordPress 3.x prior to styling]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101010-051632.png))</sub>

### 6. Style your Menu

Finally we just need to add CSS to our theme's `style.css` file and we can get a footer menu that looks like so:

[image: A Footer Nav Menu in WordPress 3.x with styling]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101010-060157.png))</sub>

The styling is very basic *so please don't hold my awful design skills against me as I'm **not** a designer nor have I ever threatened to be one!* I've included comments in the CSS code explain why I used each selector and CSS property that I did:

```
#colophon {
  padding-top:6px;        /* Move menu closer to thick black line (TwentyTen has 18px) */
}
#footernav {              /* Use same font-family as TwentyTen does for menus */
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, 'Nimbus Sans L', sans-serif;
  font-size:1.1em;        /* Make a little bigger than default */
  padding-bottom:6px;     /* Put some breathing room under the menu */
}
#footernav .menu-footer {
  text-align:center;      /* Needed to center the menu */
}
#footernav ul {
  margin:0 auto;          /* Also needed to center the menu */
  width:auto;             /* Make menu only as wide as needs to be */
  display:inline;         /* Also needed to keep width to a minumum */
}
#footernav li {
  display:inline;         /* Make menu horizontal instead of veritcal */
}
#footernav a {
  text-decoration:none;   /* Remove underlines from links */
  background-color:#ddd;  /* Create a light grey background for each option */
  color:black;            /* Make the items easy to see with text in black */
  padding:0.25em 0.5em;   /* Add space around the items for the background to display*/
  margin:0 0.5em;         /* Add space between the items */
}
#footernav a:hover {
  background-color:black; /* Surround the menu item under the mouse pointer in black */
  color:white;            /* Make the text for the same menu item be white */
}
```

That's about it! Do note that this is a tool for a designer to use so you or whomever your designer is can implement menus using this in practically whatever way you like from a *theme* perspective; just call the `wp_nav_menu()` function referencing your menus and menu locations and you're good to go!

Comment: Hi MikeSchinkel, I am very thankful to you for your answer. Really thanks. But Mike, I again have a question. Now I just want to add pages for secondary menus, As like default menus. Example : when we create a page it takes automatically place in primary links. How it is possible for secondary links?

Comment: *@Himanshu Vyas*: No, secondary menus don't automatically get links. How would it know which links go into which menus? But of you want all links in both menus then you don't need to do any of the above except to copy the `wp_nav_menu` call in `header.php` and put it in your `footer.php`, or where ever else you want it. It's perfectly okay to reuse a menu in more than one place on a theme.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Now i have clear idea about it. really very very thanks. I was extremely confused about it. Have a nice day

Comment: *@Himanshu Vyas* - You are definitely welcome, glad I could help. *Thanks in advance for selecting this answer as answering your question; just click the checkmark below to the up/down rating controls.*

Comment: Hello Mike, I have one another question. I am developing a wordpress site and right now I have a custom home page and others are default wordpress pages. Now I want to add one another custom page for some landing page. This page's layout & design is different. How Can I add this to my wordpress website?

Comment: *@Himanshu Vyas* - As that is a different question please add another question to the site making sure to write a good title that explains your question at a glance, and give as much detail as you can in text of the question. Also, since you've not accepted it as the answer, did my answer for this question not answer your question?

Comment: It was perfact answer and i did my work with the help of your answer, sorry for not accepting yet, I am going to accept it now.

Comment: *@Himanshu Vyas* - Yes, one of the reasons many of us take all the time to post good answers to your questions is to earn reputation so please always remember to reward the person who gave you a good answer by accepting their answer *(not just up-vote but also the checkmark.)*

Comment: I really want to give you reward, but to do this in this site? I am new for this website?

Comment: Hi *@Himanshu Vyas* - Are you saying you don't have enough reputation to vote up? That's not what I'm saying; anyone can *"accept"* answers to their questions. See this screen shot: http://bit.ly/accepting-answers