# Assigning Multiple Layout Designs with Custom Pages in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, design

(**Moderator's note:** This question was previously titled *"How to add multiple custom page in wordpress"*)

I am developing a WordPress site and right now I have a custom home page and others are default WordPress pages. Now I want to add one **another custom page** for some landing page. It will not be sub-page. This page's layout & design is different. How Can I add this to my wordpress website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a [**Custom Page Template**](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/13/page-templates-the-untapped-potential-of-wordpress) It's quite simple, if you want to call your layout **"My Special Layout"** just create a file in your Theme Directory calling it whatever you like *(I'd call it "page-my-special-layout.php" but that's not required)* and add the following comment to the top of the template file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Special Layout
*/
```

After the comment put in whatever HTML you need to design your desired page.

Then once you have the Template in your Theme directory and you load the Page Editor in the WordPress admin console you'll be given the option to assign it as your Page Template; simple as that:

[image: WordPress Page Editor with Page Template Selection Highlighted]

Comment: Thanks for giving me perfact answer but when I add content and save the custom page, then wordpress automatically generates primary menu according it's title. I don't want this. i just want to linked custom page with secondary menu. So how can I disable primary link in this aspect?

Comment: *@Himanshu Vyas* - Do you mean if you create a new page WordPress adds it to the primary menu automatically? Yes, it will do that unless you *explicitly* define BOTH menus and *explicitly* assign each menu to a Menu Location, otherwise it will implicitly add all pages to the primary menu.  Does that help?

Comment: yes I understand, but how to stop generating primary menu automatically when I add custom page?

Comment: @Himanshu Vyas - What I said in my previous comment; you need to **explicitly** define *BOTH* the primary and the secondary menu **including** *explicitly adding menu options to each*, and **explicitly** assign each menu to it's associated Menu Location. Have you called `register_nav_menus()` to create your secondary menu location? Have you assigned each menu to a menu location using the *Appearance > Menu* section of the admin console like I explained here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/#2760?

Comment: Ok, Now I undertand. I have an idea about it now. I am exctremely thankful for you about your about your answers for my many questions. Really very very thanks, But It may be possible that I will ask you something about it again as I am new to wordpress.

Comment: *@Himanshu Vyas* - No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Pk, Please give me a idea. If we define primary menu like secondary menu, then primary menus(default) will be displayed or not?

Comment: *@Himanshu Vyas* - Yes. Why don't you try it?