# Creating Multiple Menus in the Thesis Theme?

Tags: theme-development, menus, theme-thesis

How can I add three menus to [the Thesis theme](http://diythemes.com/thesis/)? I want a menu above the header image, one below the header image and one in the footer. A neat step by step instruction [like this for Twenty Ten](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/creating-multiple-menus-when-using-the-twentyten-theme/2760#2760) would be like the coolest answer.

Comment: I think thesis has it's own help area. If it does you would be much better off asking this there

Comment: Well i am not a good php guy and i don't understand head or tails of thesis hooks etc. I am a Copy paste Is it working guy when it comes to wordpress api :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A neat step by step instruction like
>   this for Twenty Ten would be like the
>   coolest answer.

You can follow those instruction starting at Step 3 as your working with WordPress after all.
 I'm sure Themeatic has some sort of snazzy hook but you will have to ask them.

Comment: Yes the 3rd step explained to me all, but thesis has something called hooks etc. how can i do the same with that

Answer (score 0):

If you follow those same instructions provided by Mike in the  [Creating Multiple Menus when using the TwentyTen Theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/creating-multiple-menus-when-using-the-twentyten-theme/2760#2760)  answer.  When you get to the section on editing the template is where it gets confusing with Thesis since the templates are not really the standard wordpress templates.  Since you said the thesis hooks are little confusing, and they are to many people,  I would recommend you try the OpenHook plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thesis-openhook/) and you can add php calls like below anywhere you like. Openhook creates cut and paste boxes for every Thesis hook and you can drop html, php, text anything you wish.  Also gives you easy way to remove the more common hook elements like footer attribution etc.

```
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
      'container_class' => 'menu-footer',
      'theme_location' => 'footer'
    ));
  ?>
```