# change front end menu depending on user login

Tags: menus

How can i change my front end menu depending on if the user is logged in or not?

For Example:

View 1: user is not logged in 
menu is : home , about us, testimonials

View 2: user is logged in 
menu is : dashboard, my profile, support

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define two menus and serve them based on if they are logged in or not which you can do in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'            => 'Logged In Menu',
    'container_class' => 'logged-in-menu',
    'theme_location'  => 'logged-in'
  ));
} else {
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'            => 'Visitor Menu',
    'container_class' => 'visitor-menu',
    'theme_location'  => 'visitor'
  ));
};
```

You'll also need to register their theme locations which you can do in your theme's `functions.php` file as well:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
  'logged-in'  => __( 'Logged-in Menu Area',  'yourtheme' ),
  'visitor' => __( 'Visitor Menu Area', 'yourtheme' ),
));
```

And you'll have to assign those menus to their menu locations in the admin, like so:

[image: WordPress Admin Menu Locations]

Comment: Thank you, Mike. What did you mean by "register their theme locations"? I am using the twentyten theme. What would I put for 'yourtheme'?

Comment: @rxn - *"Register theme locations"* means call `register_nav_menus()` as I showed in code above. As for your theme, create a child theme of TwentyTen instead of using it directly and then put the directory name of your child theme in place of `'yourtheme'` _"Customizing a WordPress theme without changing it?"_ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290/customizing-a-wordpress-theme-without-changing-it

Comment: Thank You for putting in the time to answer my question in great detail.