# Editing my theme to try to place the default header at the top of the page breaks the rest of the page content

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I'm using the Destro theme.

In `page.php` I copy and remove:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

And I insert it into `header.php` under:

```
<div id="wrapper_four">
```

It does the job. It displays the banner at the top of the page, but the website appears white. It's just raw html without CSS or images.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that.  When someone looks at a page on your site, WP chooses page.php to show it (that's a bit of a simplification, but is fine for this explanation).

page.php *needs* that call to `get_header()` to include the `header.php` file, which in turn will not only display the visible header of the site but usually will contain everything necessary for building the `<head>` section of the HTML document, including linking to stylesheets.  By removing that line from `page.php` you have prevented WP from creating the whole of that part of the page.

Additionally, you don't want to edit a third party theme as any later updates will overwrite your edits.  Any changes you want to make should [use a child theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/291/94267).

The best advice is that you should choose a theme that already has the header where you want it.  If for some reason that really isn't possible then creating a child theme can at least let you adjust things with some level of future proofing.